# Android Edit text alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am making a small app for a tablet, something like a display sign.

I have a few text elements that are center aligned in the display sign. When I tap on it, it gets converted to editText. I want the edit text in such a way that the text in it is center aligned and content wrapped. But when i input something, editText expands both ways, keeping the text aligned to the center. I want to do the same thing with right aligned text elements (only difference is that the edit text would expand only towards the left).

When i am trying to do this right now it expands towards the left.This is my code for laying out the edit Text element

```
tempView=new EditText(this);
((EditText) tempView).setTextSize(shrinkedFontSize);
((EditText) tempView).setTypeface(tf);
((EditText) tempView).setText(tempInput.getText());     
((EditText) tempView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
layout.addView(tempView, tempParams);
```

I am setting the width of the layout as Wrap_content in the layout parameters. I have also specified the x and y in my layout parameters for the top left corner of the edit text.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043809/android-center-text-inside-edittext-programmatically

Answer (score 48):

This should resolve your problem:

```
EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

... in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

It makes the EditText inputField entered text centered horizontally.

You can change the `layout_width` from `fill_parent` to 150 dp or any other size, but not `wrap_content`. The text will be centered horizontally.

Set the `t.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);` or `LEFT`, that makes entered text left or right alignment.

Answer (score 18):

This is a tested simpler solution. Just add `android:gravity="center"` to the layout XML file to align the text to center of EditText. There is no need to change Java code.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/LastName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: both answers are correct. however, the op were trying to do it in java so the other answer is more accurate imo