# Android: Center text inside EditText programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any way to center the inputted text in an `EditText` field? More specifically, instead of the cursor starting at the left of the box, it should start in the center and move outward towards the left as it is populated with inputs.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

you should use

```
 textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: For future readers, if you want to center both horizontally and vertically, simply use `textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`

Comment: I think it makes the vertical centering because the edittext does it automatically if central alignement isn't specified

Comment: Really? Well it seems to center it both vertically and horizontally, so I think it's good.

Comment: Careful it will cause bug in some devices of Android 5/6 , rf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017060/1074998

Answer (score 22):

Try `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` in the widget definition in your layout file. This will not strictly "move outward towards the left" -- it should move outward in both directions evenly. If you truly mean you want the text to only be on the left side of the `EditText`, I doubt that will be possible.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to do this programatically too?

Comment: @capcom: Ah, sorry, didn't realize you meant "Java" there.

Answer (score 6):

Simpler Solution to align text in EditText is to add android:gravity="center" in layout xml. There is no need to add Java code.

Tested Sample Code-

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/FieldName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:gravity="center" />
```